# jQuery UI and Fuel UX conflict

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-ui, fuelux

I use these two js libraries and both have a datepicker function, how can I resolve this conflict?
Have tried other libraries but also use the same name in the function.

Answer (score 1):

Fuel UX is modular and the controls [can be loaded individually](https://github.com/ExactTarget/fuelux/blob/master/test/browser-globals.html#L26). Some have dependencies which you can determine by viewing the source JS files.

The Fuel UX CSS only affects elements within the `.fuelux` class.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is old but just in case someone ever finds this question, fuelUX provides a no conflict method:

```
$.fn.datepicker.noConflict();
```

will revert back the "datepicker" to the previous handler (JqueryUI in this case).